# How do I do this Subversion checkout correctly?

Tags: svn

I know I'm missing something small.. please help!

I have a repo for my website project that I can access like this:

svn+ssh://myname@127.0.0.1/path/to/project/projectname

I'm trying to check it out into my webserver web root, but I always get the project folder inside the webroot, something like this:

htdocs/projectname/files (which would have to be accessed as http://mydomain/projectname/)

whereas what I obviously need is

htdocs/files (accessed as http://mydomain/)

Am I missing a simple flag somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your situation correctly, it may work if you do

```
svn+ssh://myname@127.0.0.1/path/to/project/projectname htdocs
```

You'll have to run that command from the directory that contains htdocs.  Alternatively, if you are already in the htdocs directory then

```
svn+ssh://myname@127.0.0.1/path/to/project/projectname .
```

may work.  In either case you are giving a destination for the files.

Another thing to keep in mind is if you want to do an export or a checkout.  You don't mention whether you want the server directory to contain all the versioning files.

Comment: I'm embarrassed for having had to ask a question with such a simple solution.. I tried your second example first and it did exactly what I was after. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem.  It often just takes a second pair of eyes to notice things like that.